# Coordinate Conversion - identifying source spatial reference

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

I recently acquired a shapefile that when added in ArcMap 10.2, the software says it has an unknown spatial reference system. The X and Y coordinates are both 6 digit coordinates (for example, `712568.799, 257083.471`).

I would like to be helped on how to convert these coordinates to Arc 1950 UTM Zone 36s which is a system used in Malawi. If the Y coordinate had 8 in front it could have worked perfectly but this is not the case.

Comment: Without knowing what the source coordinate system is you're going to struggle to convert it to another. Can you find out what coordinate system was used from the data provider?

Comment: The problem is even the data provider can not remember the shapefile coordinate system. However, he remembers that it was created using ArcView software. Is there a way of knowing the coordinate system without asking the data provider?

Comment: Is there a `.PRJ` file included with the shape file? I'm not an ArcGIS user but I'm pretty sure the projection data is usually stored in a `.PRJ` file with the shapefile format.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: The projection file is missing. The software is only able to draw the shapefile but projecting it seems impossible. Do you think I can create a .PRJ file from it?